# php api response not showing all results

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2, postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a select query in a function, which executed in sql command prompt, displays all results.

But in postman response, `UserInfo` is showing only 1 record as response.

```
protected function getUserSession(){
    $data = $this->params; 

    $sqlquery = "SELECT `Uid` as UID,`CreatedDate"
            . "` as CreatedDate,`Action_key` as ActionKey FROM `UsersOptStatus` ORDER BY Uid DESC LIMIT 10"; 
    $userInfoArray = array();       
    $userInfoArray = $this->getUsersOptStatusTable()->customquery($sqlquery);
    print_r($userInfoArray);

    //$uid =  $this->getUsersNewTable()->uidFromApiKey($data['UserId']);

   return array("errstr"=>"Fetching success.","success"=>1,"data"=>array('UserInfo'=>$userInfoArray));
}


public function customquery($sql) {
    $data = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql);
    return $data;
}
```

**Select Query's result:**

[image]

**Actual Result in Postman**

In raw tab, all results are fetching

[image]

In Pretty tab, it shows `Bad String`

[image]

Comment: can you comment out the print_r statement and try again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer.

Had the loop the result sets .

```
public function customquery($sql) {
    foreach (($this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql)) as $row){
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose you :

```
public function customquery($sql) {
    $data = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()->execute($sql);
    return iterator_to_array($data);
}
```